# GNU make ifeq comparison not working

Tags: c++, makefile, conditional-statements, gnu

I am trying to have a command executed depending on the current target from a list of targets (currently only one entry in that list) before another makefile is executed.

i have this:

```
$(LIBS):            
ifeq ($@,libname)
        my command here
endif
        $(MAKE) -C ./lib/$@
```

the problem is, that the `ifeq` does not get executed even if the target name is correct. Using an `$(info $@)` shows exactly the libname but the expression is not evaluated as true.
I thought maybe there is a problem with expansion of the automatic variable in a conditional so i tried using an `eval` like this:

```
$(LIBS):
        $(eval CURRENT_LIB := $@)
ifeq ($(CURRENT_LIB),libname)
        my command here
endif
        $(MAKE) -C ./lib/$@
```

info shows that the variable now equals exactly the libname but the ifeq does not get excuted.
When i enter something like `ifeq (libname,libname)` it works so the statement is working, but the comparison between variable and text does not evaluate to true even if the two are equal and it should work.
GNU make version is 4.1

What am i missing here?

Complete Makefile:

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -v -std=c++0x -pthread -Wall -g -O3

OBJ := mycode.o
OBJ += moreobjects.o
#more objects in here

LIBS = libname

.PHONY: libs $(LIBS)

SRC = $(OBJ:%.o=%.cpp)
DEPFILE := .depend

mytarget: libs $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ)

-include $(DEPFILE)

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
        $(CC) -MM -std=c++11 $(SRC) > $(DEPFILE)

libs: $(LIBS)

$(LIBS):
        $(eval CURRENT_LIB := $@)
ifeq ($(CURRENT_LIB),libname)
        ./lib/$(CURRENT_LIB)/configure
endif
        $(MAKE) -C ./lib/$@

.PHONY: clean_all
clean_all: clean
        $(foreach dir,$(LIBS),$(MAKE) clean -C ./lib/$(dir))


.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf mytarget $(OBJ) $(DEPFILE)
```

Thank You very much!

Comment: Why don't you just add an explicit rule for `libname`?

Comment: Yeah, that would work of course, i haven't even thought about that, thank you! It would still be interesting to figure out why this is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot work. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html):

> Conditionals control what 'make' actually "sees" in the makefile, so they *cannot* be used to control recipes at the time of execution.

The way I put it is that conditionals are evaluated at the time the Makefile is read. So `make` reads your Makefile, your conditional is false and it is removed.

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense! Thank You!

Comment: So what workaround should we use instead?

Comment: Down-voted. Because you only comment the `GNU make` manual. No workaround provided.

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" conditionals, don't work in a recipe with `GNU make`. Unfortunately that's true.

**Workaround:**

But you can use [Functions for Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions) and [The `eval` Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) instead. A small example for `error detection` from my build system. Here I use the `eval` and `if` function.

Snippet from `Makefile.xu`, which use `eval` and `if`:

```
xubuild_check_objects:
    $(eval RESULT = $(call xu-obj_func-valid,$(xu-src-c-y)))
    @echo 'echo nothing (dummy)' >/dev/null
    $(if $(filter n,$(RESULT)), \
    $(error XUbuild: error: xubuild_check_objects: xu-obj->xu-src-c-y override detected! Cannot build target! Aborting),)
```

**NOTE**:

```
    @echo 'echo nothing (dummy)' >/dev/null
```

This here is **required**. When `no` command will be executed after `eval`, you get a `make: Nothing to be done for 'xubuild_check_objects` message.

Project `Makefile` (root directory) with `error`:

```
# XUbuild system (MUST included first)
include Makefile.xu

# This produces an error and aborts the build
xu-src-c-y = test.c

all: xubuild_check_objects
```

Error output:

```
$ make
Makefile.xu:104: *** XUbuild: error: xubuild_check_objects: xu-obj->xu-src-c-y override detected! Cannot build target! Aborting.  Stop.
$
```

Project `Makefile` (root directory) without `error`:

```
# XUbuild system (MUST included first)
include Makefile.xu

# My build system is happy with this:
xu-src-c-y += test.c

all: xubuild_check_objects
```

Output (no error):

```
$ make
$
```

The full error detection from my build system simplified. I removed the most `Makefile.xu` "code" and only post the error detection here. (I don't explain my whole build system in this answer):

```
# XUbuild generic object
xu-obj          := :xu-obj
xu-obj_del      := :

# XUbuild object types
xu-obj_nop      := n
xu-obj_yes      := y
xu-obj_module   := m
xu-obj_src      := s
xu-obj_flag     := f

# XUbuild source priority
xu-obj_src_head     := 0
xu-obj_src_normal   := 1

# XUbuild source types
xu-obj_src_a        := 0
xu-obj_src_c        := 1
xu-obj_src_cpp      := 2

# XUbuild object functions
xu-obj_func-get     = $(filter $(xu-obj)%,$(1))
xu-obj_func-remove  = $(filter-out $(xu-obj)%,$(1))
xu-obj_func-valid   = $(if $(call xu-obj_func-get,$(1)),y,n)

# XUbuild source objects
xu-src          := $(xu-obj)$(xu-obj_del)

# XUbuild C source
xu-src-c        := $(xu-src)$(xu-obj_src_normal)$(xu-obj_del)$(xu-obj_src_c)$(xu-obj_del)
xu-src-c-       := $(xu-src-c)$(xu-obj_nop)
xu-src-c-y      := $(xu-src-c)$(xu-obj_yes)

XUBUILD_PHONY   += xubuild_check_objects
xubuild_check_objects:
    $(eval RESULT = $(call xu-obj_func-valid,$(xu-src-c-y)))
    @echo 'echo nothing (dummy)' >/dev/null
    $(if $(filter n,$(RESULT)), \
    $(error XUbuild: error: xubuild_check_objects: xu-obj->xu-src-c-y override detected! Cannot build target! Aborting),)

.PHONY: $(XUBUILD_PHONY)
```